# Menu Block change depth

Tags: navigation

I'm converting an HTML template to a Drupal theme. The HTML template has a 2-level submenu: 
`ul` (main) > `ul` (first-level) > `ul` (second level).

In my `block--system--main-menu.tpl.php` I do only have: `<?php print $content ?>`

When I check the structure of the Main menu in Drupal (list links) levels are correct.

Now on my frontpage Drupal shows only the first level of the menu. How can I make Drupal show more levels? I'd love to do this without a (non-core) module.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think you just have the primary navigation enabled in your theme. To see the second level, enable the secondary navigation in your theme settings. But this will split you're navigation. A probably better solution is, to use the "[Menu Block](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block/)" module. This allows you to build different kind of navigations in a block.